# ezPublish: Not enough arguments at [(''|ezurl()|ne('/'))]

Tags: php, ajax, ezpublish

We have received below errors:

how to resolve this

> Not enough arguments at [(''|ezurl()|ne('/'))]

In the respective file `'extension/ezcbdigeventcalendar/design/standard/templates/parts/ajaxtemplates/ajaxfullcalendarview.tpl'`

Could anyone explain how to resolve this error.

```
My code:

    {if (''|ezurl()|ne('/'))}
                    var ajaxhref={''|ezurl()}
    {else}
                    var ajaxhref={''|ezurl(,full)}
                        ajaxhref='//'+ajaxhref.split('//')[1]
    {/if}
```

Thanks
Sunil

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 0):

you should try this :

```
{if ''|ezurl()|ne('/')}
                var ajaxhref={''|ezurl()}
{else}
                var ajaxhref={''|ezurl("double","full")}
                    ajaxhref='//'+ajaxhref.split('//')[1]
{/if}
```

Regards